# Rails 3 - How to edit single nested polymorphic resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested, edit, polymorphism

In my Rails 3.0 app I have a Client model and a polymorphic Addresses model. As per the code below a client can have many addresses. I would like to my form to update a single client address at a time. I can only seem to get the [addresses_attributes] to appear if I allow all of the client's addresses to be edited at the same time. Is there a way around this?

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :addresses, :as => :addressable, :dependent => :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
```

Clients Controller

```
  def edit
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    @addresses = @client.addresses
    if params[:address]
      @address = @client.addresses.find(params[:address])
    else
      @addresses ? @address = @addresses.first : @address = []
    end
  end

   def update
     @client = Client.find(params[:id])
     @client.update_attributes(params[:client])
     redirect_to client_path(@client)
   end
```

View

```
<%= form_for @client do |f| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f} %>

  <%= f.fields_for @address  do |addresses_attributes| %>
     <%= render :partial => 'addresses/fields', :locals => {:f => addresses_attributes} %>             
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Sorry, I reread the post and realized that there were better options. You should add a scope to the Address model or you should create separate associations in the Client using conditions.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope
or see conditions here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

DETAIL:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
  named_scope :type_one, :conditions => { :address_type => 'one' }
  named_scope :type_two, :conditions => { :address_type => 'two' }

<%= f.fields_for @address.type_one  do |addresses_attributes| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'addresses/fields', :locals => {:f => addresses_attributes} %>             
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, Wilhelm Could you explain a little but more explicitly how to do that and what changes i would need to make to my model, controllers and view?

Comment: I was assuming you wanted to split by the polymorphic type. I put the detail in the answer above.

Comment: I may have confused you but i don't believe I want to split by polymorphic type. I have a client that has three different addresses. The "addressable_type" field for each is 'Client'. My issue is that if I want them to be able to edit just their first address on its own i can't get the *_attributes bit to appear.

Comment: Gocha. You could display:none on the fields and just show the one you want via JS. How are you deciding which address to have the client edit?